# Criar condição com data em formato UNIX Timestamp - Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho uma tabela na base de dados que os campos data são do tipo BigInteger, no qual recebe uma data no formato Timestamp.

Como faço para fazer um `SELECT` na tabela com as seguintes condições:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(log.id) AS QTD
FROM
    mdl_logstore_standard_log log
INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_user.id = log.userid
AND suspended = 0
AND deleted = 0
WHERE
    MONTH (
        from_unixtime(log.timecreated)
    ) = MONTH (now())
AND YEAR (
    from_unixtime(log.timecreated)
) = YEAR (now())
AND action = 'loggedin'
AND userid > 1
GROUP BY
    MONTH (
        from_unixtime(log.timecreated)
    ),
    YEAR (
        from_unixtime(log.timecreated)
    )
```

Preciso que seja o número do mês e do ano. Mas não sei converter a data usando a API de Banco de Dados do Django. Tenho isso abaixo até agora:

```
totalAccessMonth    = Log.objects.filter(timecreated__month = now.month).all()
```

---

O que eu quero é converter a coluna em tempo real para um tipo que seja data. O campo data atualmente na base é `bigint`. Eu não posso alterá-lo no banco.

Preciso dessa consulta acima nos moldes de Django.

Por enquanto tenho isso:

```
Log.objects.filter(action = 'loggedin', userid__gt = 1) \
.extra(select={'timecreated_year' : 'YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated))'}) \
.extra(select={'timecreated_month' : 'MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated))'}) \
.values_list('timecreated_month', flat = True) \
.aggregate(Count('id'))
```

Comment: Nessa sua consulta de exemplo, você gostaria de adicionar o ano também como condição? Assim, por exemplo: timecreated__month = now.month, timecreated__year = now.year.

Comment: Gostaria. O problema é que assim não funciona, devido ao tipo de campo.

Comment: Utilizando raw_sql, seria algo assim?
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT cast(EXTRACT(year FROM coluna) as bigint) as ANOS '
     'FROM despesa_tbl WHERE cd_usuario = %s '
     'GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM coluna) ' 
     'ORDER BY EXTRACT(year FROM coluna) DESC ', 
     [request.user.id])

Comment: Mas não tem como fazer usando ORM?

Comment: Eu não conheço um modo; quando precisei fazer isso eu partir para raw_sql. Vou estudar sobre isso e se conseguir alguma solução eu volto e comento.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi a dúvida, dado o seguinte model:

```
from django.db import models

class Log(models.Model):
      timecreated = model.BigIntegerField()
```

Você consegue montar sua QuerySet usando o argumento `range` do método `filter`, da seguinte forma:

```
import datetime
import calendar

now = datetime.datetime.now()
start_date = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
end_date =  datetime.date(now.year, now.month, monthrange(now.year, now.month)[1])

Log.objects.filter(createdtime__range=(start_date.strftime("%s"), end_date.strftime("%s")))
```

Isto por que os métodos `get`, `filter` e `exclude` dos modelos do Django aceitam diversos argumentos, que seriam digamos assim, os "where" do SQL.

O `range` é equivalente ao `BETWEEN` do SQL, e pode ser usado com números, datas e até caracteres.

Vale dar uma olhada neste documento:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

E neste também:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#range

O exemplo citado acima foi feito com `Python 3.6` e `Django 2.0`

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Eu preciso comparar apenas o mês e ano da data que está no banco. Seu Model está correto. Mas como o campo é Bigint, como faço para extrair dele apenas o mês e o ano na comparação? Dentro do filter

Comment: Se entendi, você quer extrair todos os registros do model Log, e então comparar o ano e mês de cada um, seria isso? Caso não seja isso, e você queira extrair apenas de um Ano/Mês específico, acredito que a solução apresentada resolva, você apenas precisa criar um objeto "datetime" com a data deseja ao invés do "now" usado acima e usar o range. De qualquer forma, se eu entendi errado e quiser tentar explicar de outra forma, estou a disposição. Abraço

Comment: Não, mano! Não... Eu quero o meu exemplo do POST.

Comment: Entendi. Não conheço um modo